# Magento reports an install error: "Database server does not support the InnoDB storage engine"

Tags: php, html, magento

While installing Magento on server I got the following error

```
Database server does not support the InnoDB storage engine.

Database connection error.
```

How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to contact your host to find out if they are able to offer a server that contains a MySQL install which supports the InnoDB storage engine. Magento requires InnoDB (unfortunately).

Alternatively, you may want to google 'fastest magento host' and take your pick of the lot.

Answer (score 1):

Contact your ***server support team*** to get the issue resolved. Tell them about the error and they will provide you with alternative/solution that supports ***InnoDB***.

Comment: A lot of shared hosts don't allow InnoDB or only have it on a select farm of servers as well.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the hosting company.

1. if you have SSH, Login into you VPS with SSH and root
2. Open the following file (nano /etc/my.cnf)
3. Find the following line and comment it out. (skip-inndob) remove the #
   `[mysqld]
   #skip-inndob`
4. Now login into your WHM, Go to "Restart Services" and click on: SQL Server (MySQL), Then confirm the process with a “Yes”

All of these steps should activate the InnoDB module, you can test it by going into your phpMyAdmin > SQL
Enter: show engines; command into the empty field and press 
It should give the output:

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. this worked for me